# How to stop csh set from removing braces inside single quotes?

Tags: csh

In the following code, it seems that {} are removed from inside single quotes when using set but not when using alias. How can I stop set from removing the braces?

```
set variable = "middle"
set string = 'echo ${ENVVAR}_'$variable'_end'
echo $string
```

When running the script I would expect to see:

```
echo ${ENVVAR}_middle_end
```

But instead I get:

```
echo $ENVVAR_middle_end
```

How can I stop csh from removing my braces?

Comment: If you're writing scripts in `csh` the correct answer is always "don't do that".  See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/ and http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces are not within quotes when you echo the string, so quote the variable expansion in the last `echo`:

```
set variable = "middle"
set string = 'echo ${ENVVAR}_'$variable'_end'
echo "$string"
```

Result with `csh`:

```
echo ${ENVVAR}_middle_end
```